# How to prevent assets in bundles yii2 with timestamp

Tags: jquery, yii2

I have an Asset Bundle like this :

```
class BarangLokasiAsset extends AssetBundle
{

public $basePath = '@webroot';
public $baseUrl = '@web';
public $sourcePath = '@bower';
public $css = [
    "css/x3dom.css"
];
public $js = [
    'js/x3dom.js',
    'js/scene3d.jquery.js',
];
public $depends = [
    'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
];

public $publishOptions = [
    'forceCopy' => true,
    'appendTimestamp' => false,
];

public $jsOptions = [
    'appendTimestamp' => false,
];

}
```

I see in console, the js that created like this : `x3dom.js?_=1506319654909` and `scene3d.jquery.js?_=1506319654910` .

But the css is fine : `x3dom.css`

How to make those js without timestamp ?
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below code in your config file:

```
return [
    // ...
    'components' => [
        'assetManager' => [
            'appendTimestamp' => false,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: Yes I have add this, but, it will make all my assets bundle is without timestamp and also not working too. Beside, I just need in this AssetBundle without timestamp.

Comment: Just updated the answer. I've not tested it so let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Got this error , message
:
"Setting unknown property: app\assets\BarangLokasiAsset::appendTimestamp"
name
:
"Unknown Property"

Comment: Updated. Try with publishOptions.

Comment: Not works too. Beside, What the differences with my code above, : public $publishOptions = [
    'forceCopy' => true,
    'appendTimestamp' => false,
];

Comment: I think it's an AssetManager property, so it can only be applied to all assets.